# injecting ConversionService into a custom Converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring mvc-3. I am writing a custom Converter which needs access to other Converters registered to a ConversionService.

How can I accomplish this? I tried writing my custom converter as:

```
  class CustomConverter<X, Y>{
     @Autowired ConversionService service;
     //+getter & setters of service

     public Y convert(X input){
          // I need access to service to lookup simple conversions such as
          // String array to Long array etc..

     }

  }
```

And I registered my custom converter via applicationContext.xml

```
  <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
     <property name = "converters">
         <list>
            <bean class="CustomConverter"/>
         </list>
     </property>
  </bean>
```

However, spring refuses to inject service into my CustomConverter(its always null). How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used something like this recently to solve this problem.
Use a custom factory :

```
public class MyConversionServiceFactoryBean extends ConversionServiceFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        ConversionService conversionService = getObject();
        ConverterRegistry registry = (ConverterRegistry) conversionService;
        // register converters that need a nested conversion service
        registry.addConverter(new MyCustomConverter(conversionService));
    }
}
```

which is declared like this :

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="com.company.MyConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            ... declare standard converters here ...
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion! Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that MyCustomConverter isn't managed by spring container

Answer (score 10):

I have come across same problem. There's an [issue SPR-6415](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6415) in Spring JIRA covering this problem. I've giving here my solution based on discussion in this issue. It's the same principle like answer of @nmervaillie but you don't have to implement your own `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

```
/**
 * Base class of @{code Converter} that need to use {@code ConversionService}.
 * Instances of implementing classes must be spring-managed to inject ConversionService.
 * 
 * @author Michal Kreuzman
 */
public abstract class CoversionServiceAwareConverter<S, T> implements Converter<S, T> {

  @Inject
  private ConversionService conversionService;

  protected ConversionService conversionService() {
    return conversionService;
  }

  /**
   * Add this converter to {@code ConverterRegistry}.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  @PostConstruct
  private void register() {
    if (conversionService instanceof ConverterRegistry) {
      ((ConverterRegistry) conversionService).addConverter(this);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Can't register Converter to ConverterRegistry");
    }
  }
}

@Component
public class SampleConverter extends CoversionServiceAwareConverter<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public String convert(Object source) {
        ConversionService conversionService = conversionService();

        // Use conversionService and convert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in spring-ws centric application. The main components of this solutions are:

- declaring Converter implementations as spring beans
- using @Lazy from spring-context on the injection points in the converters
- inject all discovered converters in a ConversionServiceFactoryBean

SampleConverter

```
@Component
public class SampleConverter implements Converter<Source, Target> {

private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Inject
    @Lazy
    public SampleConverter(ConversionService conversionService){
        this.conversionService = conversionService; 
    }

    @Override
    public Target convert(Source source){
        Target target = new Target();
        ...
    target.setTargetDetails(conversionService.convert(source.getSourceDetails, TargetDetails.class); 
    ...
```

and the Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConversionServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService(Set<Converter<?,?>> converters){
        ConversionServiceFactoryBean csfb = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
        csfb.setConverters(converters); 
        csfb.afterPropertiesSet(); 
        return csfb.getObject(); 
   }
```

...

The @Lazy annotations circumvents the egg-chicken problem by injecting a proxy and thus delaying the resolution of the conversionservice bean until it is really used.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem (that i've encountered) is when you use `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` for building `conversion service` that includes converters that use `conversion service` as well is that you get error because of `ConversionServiceFactoryBean.getObject` method that provides instance of `conversion service` is being called prior to `ConversionServiceFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet` where that conversion service instance is actually created.

So, **to avoid this behavior**, you just need **to create `conversion service` prior to `ConversionServiceFactoryBean.getObject` is called**. I've made it in constructor of class that extends `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`. 
Example:

```
    try {

        Field serviceField = ConversionServiceFactoryBean.class.getDeclaredField("conversionService");
        conversionServiceField.setAccessible(true);
        conversionServiceField.set(this, createConversionService());

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException fieldAccessError) {

        fieldAccessError.printStackTrace();
        //or do some log output here, it's up to you
    }
```

Than you can use converters that uses `conversion service` as well. 
Hope it helps.