# Complex Spring Converter with Converter inside?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a complex Object that would require nested Converter say I have class B which includes instance of A.

```
 class A {
    ....
   }

   class B {
    A a;
    ....
   }
```

I wrote a converter for A that converts to some other class say "AA".
Now I need to write a converter that converts B to some other class as well. Since B has A in it. I need to convert A to this other thing "AA". 
I am utilizing the Converter pattern. 
and saw this ans:
[injecting ConversionService into a custom Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336387/injecting-conversionservice-into-a-custom-converter)
Is there a better way than this? I would prefer not to initialize a converter in a custom factory class.

Answer (score 3):

With class BB like:

```
class BB {
  ....
  AA aa;
  ....
}
```

You can simply do:

```
public BB convert(B b) {

  BB bb = new BB();
  bb.aa = new AToAAConverter().convert(b.a);
  ....
```

You can still register your `AToAAConverter` in `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution without writing custom conversionService, use @Lazy annotation to solve the cycle dependencies.

The `Configuration` class like:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private ConversionService mConversionService;

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(aConverter());
        registry.addConverter(bConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public AConverter aConverter() {
        return new AConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public BConverter bConverter() {
        return new BConverter(mConversionService);
    }
}
```

`AConverter` and `BConverter` both implements  `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<S,T>`, as `AConverter` convert class `A` to `AA` and `BConverter` convert class `B` to another class which has `A` in it.

**Update**

Inject `ConversionService` in `WebConfig` constructor is better, which can avoid field injection:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ConversionService mConversionService;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfig(@Lazy ConversionService conversionService) {
        mConversionService = conversionService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. Create a converter service and inject a set of converter beans you declare. In some cases you converters may need access to converterService. You can get around the circular ref by using @Lazy annotation. You may need the @Primary to let spring know that the converterService you declared should be injected with priority if other conversionServices exist. In some cases its useful to have converters have access to conversion service. You can maintain loose coupling by having conversion service dispatch to the correct converter from inside of current converters. In addition, this allows you to re-use a converters that are common, from other converters, eliminating code duplication.

```
/**
 * @author vsutskever 3/22/18
 **/
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfig {


  /**
   * Circular reference. This beans depends on Conversion service. Using @Lazy to resolve.
   * @param service
   * @return
   */
  @Bean
  public Converter dispositionMessageConverter(
      @Lazy ConversionService service){
    return new DispositionMessageRequestToOutgoingMessage(service);
  }

  /**
   * Circular reference. This beans depends on Conversion service. Using @Lazy to resolve.
   * @param service
   * @return
   */
  @Bean
  public Converter contentMessageRequestToOutgoingMessageConverter(
      @Lazy ConversionService service){
    return new ContentMessageRequestToOutgoingMessageConverter(service);
  }

  @Bean
  public Converter incomingRcsMessageToBaseMessageConverter(){
    return new IncomingRcsMessageToBaseMessageConverter();
  }

  @Bean
  public Converter contactToAddressConverter(){
    return new ContactToAddressConverter();
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ConversionService conversionService(List<Converter> converters){
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(new HashSet<>(converters));
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing something similar (using Spring 3.1.1), fairly new to spring but after a bit of trial and error this worked for me. It supports nested converters and converters use spring annotation instead of having to set them all up in a @Configuration class.

```
------ConversionFactoryBean.java-------
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Qualifier("conversionService")
public class ConversionFactoryBean extends ConversionServiceFactoryBean {
    // spring will inject beans by type
    @Autowired
    public Set <CustomConverter<?, ?>> customConverters;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {

        // Set the custom converters (default converters will be handled by parent).
        setConverters(customConverters);

        // registers the custom converters
        super.afterPropertiesSet();

        // set the conversionService on the converters
        final ConversionService conversionService = getObject();
        for (Object converter : customConverters) {
            ((CustomConverter<?, ?>) converter).setConversionService(conversionService);
        }
    }
}

------CustomConverter.java-------
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

/**
 * Base class of converters, providing access to conversionservice.
 * @param <S> the source object to convert, which must be an instance of S
 * @param <T> the converted object, which must be an instance of T
 */
public abstract class CustomConverter<S, T> implements Converter<S, T> {

    private ConversionService conversionService;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public CustomConverter() {
        super();
    }

    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        return conversionService;
    }

    public void setConversionService(ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }
}

------ConsumerSummaryConverter.java-------
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConsumerSummaryConverter 
    extends CustomConverter <CustomerDetail, ConsumerSummary> {

    public ConsumerSummaryConverter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public ConsumerSummary convert(CustomerDetail source) {
        // use nested converter
        Individual ind = getConversionService().convert(source, Individual.class);
        // do rest of conversion...
    }
}

-----ServiceConfig.java------
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"uk.co.my.custom.converter"})
public class ServiceConfig { // empty at the moment}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to convert `B` to `BB` why not inject `Converter<A, AA>` into `BToBbConverter`?

```
@Component
public class BToBbConverter implements Converter<B, BB> {
  private final Converter<A, AA> aToAaConverter;

  public BToBbConverter(Converter<A, AA> aToAaConverter) {
    this.aToAaConverter = aToAaConverter;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public BB convert(B source) {
    // use aToAaConverter here
  }
}
```