# Spring Boot Entity to DTO ConverterNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto

I have a simple API, built with Spring Boot, where I am trying to convert entity classes to the corresponding dtos.

**Student Entity**

```
@Entity(name = "students")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student extends AbstractUpdatable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "student_first_name", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "First name is mandatory")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "student_last_name", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Last name is mandatory")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "student_ssn", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "SSN is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    private String ssn;

    @Column(name = "student_age")
    @Min(5)
    @Max(100)
    private Integer studentAge;

    @Column(name = "student_email")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "student_level")
    private Integer studentLevel; // TODO could be enum or separate entity

    @Column(name = "student_creation_date")
    private Date creationDate; // TODO check spring's feature to manage creation and update dates (auditing)

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    public Student() {
        this.creationDate = new java.util.Date(); // TODO this will be removed when spring's auditing is utilized
    }

}
```

**Group Entity**

```
@Entity(name = "groups")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Group extends AbstractUpdatable<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String Name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Student> students;

}
```

**Student DTO**

```
public class StudentDto extends AbstractStudentDto implements Serializable {

    private final Long id;

    private final Date creationDate;

    public StudentDto(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Long id, GroupDto group, Integer studentAge, Integer studentLevel,
                      Date creationDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.group = group;
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
        this.studentLevel = studentLevel;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }
}
```

**Group DTO**

```
public class GroupDto extends AbstractGroupDto{

    private final Long id;

    public GroupDto(Long id, String name, List<StudentDto> students) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.students = students;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**GroupToGroupDtoConverter**

```
@Component
public class GroupToGroupDtoConverter implements org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<Group, GroupDto> {

    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    @Autowired
    public GroupToGroupDtoConverter(ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    public GroupDto convert(Group source) {

        var convertedStudents = new ArrayList<StudentDto>();

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(source.getStudents())) {
            source.getStudents().forEach(student ->
                    convertedStudents.add(conversionService
                            .convert(student, StudentDto.class)));
        }

        return new GroupDto(source.getId(), source.getName(), convertedStudents);
    }
}
```

And a very similar **StudentToStudentDtoConverter**.

The issue is that when the code needs to do the conversion from any of the entities to their dtos I get

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
> converter found capable of converting from type
> [com.studentmanagement.model.Group] to type
> [com.studentmanagement.dto.group.GroupDto]

Now if I try to remove the conversion of the students' list to a list of student dtos in the converter above, so the converter looks like this:

```
@Component
    public class GroupToGroupDtoConverter implements org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<Group, GroupDto> {
    
        @Override
        public GroupDto convert(Group source) {
            return new GroupDto(source.getId(), source.getName(), new ArrayList<StudentDto>());
        }

    }
```

The conversion works with no issues (with a dummy students list of course). Am I missing something when I am adding the conversion service inside my converters?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate the issue and did a small working demo on this.

One thing I found while doing that, that could be relevant to your case, is that injecting a conversion service into a converter is not trivial (see e.g. [this](https:///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331823/complex-spring-converter-with-converter-inside) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336387/injecting-conversionservice-into-a-custom-converter) relevant issues).

Also, important as well, do not forget to register the converters, as shown below on the code samples, and e.g. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions). From the error message you posted, seems like the service cannot find the needed converter.

For my demo, please note I removed the group field from the StudentDTO class to simplify things. I hope it helps, happy to share the full code as well in github.

I used the following converter for Group:

```
@Component
public class GroupToGroupDtoConverter implements org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<Group, GroupDto> {

    private ConversionService conversionService;

    public GroupToGroupDtoConverter(ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    public GroupDto convert(Group group) {


        List<StudentDto> studentDtoList =
                group.getStudents().stream().map(a -> conversionService.convert(a, StudentDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        GroupDto groupDto = new GroupDto(group.getId(), group.getName(), studentDtoList);

        return groupDto;
    }
}
```

But in order to successfully inject the conversion service and register the converters I added this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new GroupToGroupDtoConverter(conversionService));
        registry.addConverter(new StudentToStudentDtoConvervter());

    }
}
```

If, for example, I comment out the first addConverter line, I get the Converter not found exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.example.conversion_entities.Group] to type [com.example.conversion_entities.GroupDto]
```

Once all is done, the following test passes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class GroupToGroupDtoConverterTest {


    @Autowired
    ConversionService conversionService;


    @Test
    void convert() {
        Student studentA = new Student();
        studentA.setFirstName("John");
        studentA.setLastName("Doe");

        Student studentB = new Student();
        studentB.setFirstName("Jane");
        studentB.setLastName("Doe");

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        studentList.add(studentA);
        studentList.add(studentB);

        Group group = new Group(1L, "groupA", studentList);

        GroupDto convertedGroupDto = conversionService.convert(group, GroupDto.class);
        assertEquals("John", convertedGroupDto.getStudents().get(0).getFirstName());
        assertEquals("Jane", convertedGroupDto.getStudents().get(1).getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is ConversionService can't convert your classes by default. Instead try to inject a class implementing ConversionService with correct convert method implementation inside.