# How to create custom component model for MapStruct?

Tags: java, spring, converters, mapstruct

[MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#configuration-options) provides component models for creating converters. But, these converters are generated like independent Spring components. Is there a way to "put" them into [ConversionService](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService.html)?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18249958/1251549) is an example of adding Spring converters to conversion service. Is there a way of creating a custom component model which uses `CoversionServiceAwareConverter` as super class?

Answer (score 0):

We haven't looked into Spring's conversion service yet, so there is no support for this provided out of the box.

You cannot create custom component models atm., but couldn't you just register the generated mappers manually with the conversion service?

Comment: That being said, I'd be very interested in any findings on your side, should it turn out there's anything to do on the MapStruct side to support this use case, I'd be willing to help with this.

Comment: "but couldn't you just register the generated mappers manually" - yes I can. But it leads to very long long xml or `@Bean` annotated method. So adding postconstruct annotation with adding to `ConversionService` reduce it a lot.

Comment: **Note** that when using conversion service together with mapstruct you got best from 2 worlds: avoid writing converters by hand (mapstruct) and reduce dependencies of converters (spring). So such functionality will be  really good.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you mean by "reduce dependencies of converters"; Working with typed interfaces is one of the advantages of MapStruct, the generic contract of ConversionService looses that. If you like, open a feature request at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues and we can discuss it in more detail there.